Reloading vim file after editing from another window?
Say I am editing the file CMakeLists.txt from two vim sessions. If I make an edit to the file in one session, save my changes, and then switch to my other session I get prompted with the following:
W11: Warning: File "CMakeLists.txt" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File: 

I like this functionality and it works on all of the devices I have but when trying on a new device I don't seem to be able to replicate it at all. When running :help W11 it says Set the 'autoread' option if you want to do this automatically. but even on the devices this works on I don't set this in my .vimrc file.
Any ideas on how to get this working? I've tried set autoread in the .vimrc on the device but that doesn't trigger it either.
Edit:
here is my .vimrc for reference:
syntax on
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set smarttab
set smartindent
set autoindent
set expandtab
set linebreak
syntax enable
set number
set si
set laststatus=2
set ruler
set wildmenu
set noswapfile
set hlsearch


Why are you editing one file with two Vims?

two terminal sessions both invoking vim CMakeLists.txt. Easy to edit large files if I'm doing some work at the top and the bottom of it

Thank you for clarifying. It was more of a rhetorical question meant to imply it's not a good idea. On the device where it's set, do :verbose set autoread?.

Could you tell us what is the result of the command set autoread?? Could you tell us what is the output of the :echo $MYVIMRC command?

On the machine that it works but I don't explicitly specify set autoread in my .vimrc it returns noautoread

I also wanted to add it's pretty valuable if I am running something like clang-format and want to reload the current file I'm in with it's new formatting changes

We can also image some custom mechanism based on event. Could you tell us what is the result of verbose autocmd FileChangedShell or verbose autocmd FileChangedPost?

Just to be clear: with :set noautoread you will see the warning that the file changed, with :set autoread you won't see the warning and Vim will read it automatically. This is the intended behavior.

On the device this is working on, regardless if autoread or noautoread is set I am still getting the option to load the file with new changes. I don't mind this but I am trying to get this working on another device I am using

It is always working. The difference is that you'll see W11 with :set noautoread.

I wish that 'noautoread' would trigger this but doesn't seem to be the case for some reason. Unless vim 8.1 and 8.2 vary in this functionality, I am unsure why one machine invokes this prompt by default regardless of autoread setting and the other refuses to show the prompt. This SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090335/use-checktime-with-autocmd-without-delay-in-vim/22092122# was a janky hack to get the W11/W12 prompts to show but only when trying to save the file again.

"Easy to edit large files if I'm doing some work at the top and the bottom of it" Wouldn't it be even easier to just do that in Vim by opening the file in two windows? The problem would disappear entirely.

@romainl There are other uses cases. If you had read thru the comments, I had stated running a formatter like clang-format is one of them

I have read the comments and that doesn't sound like another use case.
